# Send daily emails at time a user has set with PHP and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, cron

I need to send emails to every user every day, but the time of sending is selected by a user. Now I made it this way: I have a table emails, where I store user_id and the text of email. My cron job script selects emails that should be sent in time within 5 minutes.

After that I put them in Queuee::delay() for minutes and insert email in in table sent_today. When I call my script next time, it does not take emails from sent_today.

Is there a better solution for that?

Comment: i would have done it exactly like you, it seems fine to me. but I'm not a highly experienced dev so I'm also looking forward to learning a better solution if it exists.